# image not appearing in javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

for some reason, I can't seem to get my heroImage to appear on the screen. Any help on why it is not appearing is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
<html>
<style>
#myheroimg{

}
</style>
<body>

<canvas width="500" height="500" id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 512;
canvas.height = 480;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var heroImage= new Image();
heroImage.onload=function(){

}
heroImage.src="hero.jpg";

var hero={
x:5,
y:5
};

document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('background.jpg')";

function main(){
ctx.drawImage(heroImage, 10, 10);
}
main();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know you have an accepted answer, but can I just ask what are you going to use your heroImage for? moving around? or did you just want to drawn a static image.

Comment: I was planning on using keyboard controls to move the image around, and spawning other objects at other positions in the canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to move the call to the function `main()` inside the `heroImage.onload` and get the 2d context after adding it to the `document.body`.

Why do you add a new canvas anyways, if you already have one?
Why do you change the body background image in javascript?
... etc

Anyways, try this:

```
<html>
<style>
<body>
<script>
     var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
     document.body.appendChild(canvas);
     canvas.width = 512;
     canvas.height = 480;
     var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    function main(){
        ctx.drawImage(heroImage, 10, 10);
    }

    var heroImage= new Image();
    heroImage.onload=function(){
        main();
    }
    heroImage.src="hero.jpg";

    var hero={
        x:5,
        y:5
    };

    document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('background.jpg')";

</script>
</body>
</html>
```